OSX with ExFat external drive not fully accessible from Windows clients
As the title says, I have an old Mac running 10.13 (High Sierra) with an 16TB external drive formatted to ExFat that serves as my main "backup" drive for every computer in my home.
Some background: I used to have a 5TB drive (formatted as HFS+) for this and everything (i.e. all the scenarios listed below that aren't working on the new drive) worked flawlessly. But space was running low so I wanted to upgrade to a newer one. Given that my Mac is also pretty old, I wanted the new drive formatted in ExFat so when the Mac dies I could then, and only then, swap it to a newer PC.
The issues: On the Mac, I can copy the files to the new drive using Beyond Compare and my cloud backup service seems to have no problem seeing the new files and even thinks they match with the existing backup set so it doesn't try to upload them again. This is great.
But on all my Windows machines that connect it, things started to not work with the new drive. Chrome can't save downloads to it and gives a completely unspecified error. I can't manually add files to the drive. Let's say I connect to the drive and open up an existing folder. I can see files in there. But if I right-click and choose New -> Rich Text Document, Windows immediately says "Unable to create file 'foo'. There is not enough space on the disk." Winamp can no longer scan the folders on the new drive (I can't find any errors). There are other oddities but these are the main ones for me. Like I said above, all of these scenarios work fine when connecting to the older HFS+ drive from my Windows machines but not the new ExFat drive. And I can do everything on the Mac with no issues (at least with Chrome downloads and creating files). I have tried connecting to the drive via \\<machine>\<driveName> and trying to share individual folders on the drive. Same results. It looks to be how the Mac is opening connections to Windows but I don't know what the fix is, if any.
Any ideas here would be appreciated. But I'm keen on keeping the backup drive on the Mac as long as that machine is working.
EDIT: As asked, here is the screenshot of my "Sharing & permissions" section of my drive info. I looked into this message before I even asked this question here and it seems like this is a normal message for ExFat since OSX doesn't have any ability to assign permissions on that type of partition (at least that was my understanding).


How is the drive connected?  Do you unmount/unplug it from the Mac and then plug it directly into one of the Windows machines, or are you using one of the machines (Mac or Windows) as a file server, or is it an NAS (connected only to the network)?

Welcome to Ask Different. Did you format the drive with macOS? The drive is quite large, it could be some formatting difference that Windows can’t deal with. I’d recommend that create a new partition using the drive’s free space, format it as ExFAT with Windows (see https://superuser.com/questions/1086749/how-do-i-format-an-internal-hard-drive-to-exfat-in-windows-10#1086753) and test if you can read and write files on both macOS and Windows. If that’s the case, you can format the whole drive with Windows. If it doesn’t work, it could be a bug in macOS’s implementation of the exFAT file system.

@gidds It is connected to the Mac via USB. My windows machines connect to the Mac to get to the drive.

@jaume I don't think the partition/formatting is the issue. I can wipe the drive and format it when connected to Windows. The only difference is that OSX can only read an ExFat when 128k is used for block size. So in order to use the drive on the Mac it needs to be formatted by the Mac. Another reason I think Windows is not the issue is that Windows can read files off it just fine when it is formatted & connected to the Mac. I'm like 85% sure it's a permission thing on the Mac when using ExFat but I just can't find a whole lot of info about my particular situation to confirm the this.

So, to summarize: you have an exfat drive connected to your Mac which you export via File Sharing and the Windows machine accesses that File Share over the network?

I was under the impression you plugged the exFAT drive into your Windows computer, that’s why I thought it could be a formatting problem, but yes, if you connect to the drive over the network with a UNC path like \computer\path then the formatting is not the problem. You need to configure read-access for your Mac user on the Mac and enter that user and password when connecting the drive on Windows.

@nohillside Basically yes. The only thing I will say is that I don't explicitly share the drive. File sharing is on. But, from a Windows machine I can just go to \ and I see all the drives connected to my Mac (I have the same user on my Mac and Windows machines) and then I map a drive to the backup drive.

@jaume I do not think you are correct because I currently have both the new backup and the old backup drives and I can read/write to the old one fine but can only read from the new one.

Can you go to /Volumes, select the drive and press Cmd-I and add a screenshot of the Sharing section at the bottom to the question?

@nohillside I updated the post with the screenshot. Sorry it took me a bit to get back to it.

Well, we need to see the details as we (the rights you actually have), not just the titles.

I must have misunderstood the process. Where am I going to "go to /Volumes"?

In Finder, type Shift-Cmd-G, type /Volumes and press enter. Then select (don't open) the directory showing your external drvive, type Cmd-I and add a screenshot of the lower part, with the permissions.

Did it and the process yielded nothing different than what I have already posted. Under "Sharing & Permissions", when expanded, all it says is "You have custom access." That's it. Nothing more. There are no further details in that section. And this looks to be expected on ExFat drives as I see others reporting the same (though their particular issues are different than mine which is why I created this question).
